# Angular directive API: component uses of `controller` and `controllerAs` in the `directiveDefinitionObject`

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, components

I am reading the [Angular Directives API documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api), trying to understand it, in the hope that I might be able to create a simple reusable component with its own *encapsulated* methods, methods that could be exposed to an external scope, i.e. to the controller of the page on which this component is placed.

There is a `controller` property in the `DirectiveDefinitionObject`, as well as a `controllerAs` property.

**My question: can the `controller` property, which points to a function, be used to encapsulate an object whose methods can be invoked by an external scope? Could those encapsulated methods be exposed to the page controller's scope via the component-directive's `controllerAs` property?**

Here's the component I'm trying to create, so my question won't be so abstract.  I want to have a checklist component

```
[ ] onions     (2)
[ ] peppers    (4)
[ ] mushrooms  (8)
```

where each checkbox is associated with a specific bit value (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64...). The component would expose an attribute that was the sum(bits) of the checked items. That *single integer value*   would be bound to a page scope variable, `$scope.pizzaToppings`.  With two-way binding, if the checklist component were bound to the value 6, then [x] onions and [x] peppers would be checked, but not mushrooms.

I have this partly working, except that the "component" is not self-aware. The checklist is just a template-expanding directive. The "component" does not compute its own sum(bit). Rather, I have an external function in the page scope that iterates the model.